# Add a Rule to S3BucketLifecycleConfiguration

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set a new expiration date in days for my bucket, however I am having a hard time adding the rule to the bucket. This is what I got far:

```
    S3BucketLifecycleConfigurationRule *testRule = [[S3BucketLifecycleConfigurationRule alloc] initWithId:@"My Rule" andPrefix:self.newRuleTextField.text andExpirationInDays:1 andStatus:@"ENABLE"];
```

After this I know I need to add this rule to a S3BucketLifecycleConfiguration instance so I can finally call the request method, but I cant figure out how to add it to the S3BucketLifecycleConfiguration

```
    S3SetBucketLifecycleConfigurationRequest *setBucketLifecycleConfigurationRequest = [[S3SetBucketLifecycleConfigurationRequest alloc] initWithBucketName:self.bucketName withConfiguration:myConfig;
```

Thank yall in advance

Answer (score 1):

`S3BucketLifecycleConfiguration` has a property called `rules` that contains a list of `S3BucketLifecycleConfigurationRule`s. The following should work:

```
S3BucketLifecycleConfiguration *myConfig = [S3BucketLifecycleConfiguration new];
myConfig.rules = [NSArray arrayWithObject:testRule];
```